# Как поставить Python на Android

Tags: python, android

Бесплатных вариантов не нашёл. Есть ли вообще такое? Если есть, то нормально ли работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для Android существует т.н. [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) (Scripting Layer for Android), который позволяет исполнять скрипты различных интерпретаторов на Android. В принципе, информации в сети по SL4A [хватает](http://www.google.ru/search?q=sl4a). Так-же есть пара статей [на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/tag/sl4a/).

Answer (score 1):

С оффициального сайта(ссылка выше) скачиваем Python for Android apk-шку. Ставим на эмулятор или девайс(adb install PythonForAndroid.apk). Дальше запускаем, он начинает качать интерпретатор и либы. Для удобства нужно также поставить SL4A apk-шку, чтобы выполнять скрипты в терминале, редактировать их и т.д.

Других реализаций пока не видел.